# Does C++ have an operator that doesn't need a semicolon at the end?

Tags: c++, syntax

I need something in front of a string but in the end I can't have a semicolon. Does C++ have an operator that doesn't need a semicolon in the end? Generally I can think in programming we can say `#define X 5` and that needs no semicolon, but in C++ except macros, can we find any operator that has no need for a semicolon?

```
int main(){
   SOMETHING "hello world"
}
```

What can I write above to have "..." "hello"?
I need something in front of a string but in the end I can't have a semicolon.

**I know my question is mysterious — sorry!**

- ### **update**

I mean statements not C++ operators.

I want to write something like:

```
FUNC class_inst WITH "hello world"
```

`FUNC` is a macro, `class_inst` is a class instance, and I am wondering if I can write something like `WITH "string"` but I want someone to answer me if something matches to macro `WITH` to have this in my `main` function.

Comment: is this a quiz online?

Comment: no i need answer curiously ..

Comment: what would cause you to be curious of this?

Comment: well it doesn't make sense, so there is no good answer.

Comment: Technically, none of the C++ operators needs a semicolon at the end; it is statements than need semicolons at the end.  So, `a = b + c;` has two operators, `=` and `+`, and neither needs a semicolon, but the statement as a whole needs a semicolon to mark its end.

Comment: your question does not make any sense.  rather than saying you want to write C++ without semicolons instead explain what it is you want to express so that we can give you some idea of an approach.

Comment: im sorry i mean statements.. so is clear that semicolon is essential in every c++ statement instruction

Comment: `#define SOMETHING(v) v;` then use `SOMETHING("hello world")` ...

Comment: extra bracket at then end :)

Comment: Without knowing *why* you want this, it's a little hard to guide you. I'd suggest replacing some of that mystery with a pinch of useful information, lest your question be closed.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're seeking with the notation specified in the update to the question.  If you used 'function notation' (`WITH("hello world")`), all sorts of things become possible.  While you use space separated words, you're limited to object-like macros and they can't add anything after the material that follows the macro name.

Comment: If you want a language other than C++, there are many to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to use operators without a semicolon. You can do them in an `if` condition. For example:

```
if(x=5){} 
//this statement assigns 5 to x. So it is assignment without semicolon
if(x=a+b){}   //this puts result of a+b in x.
```

Comment: Interesting thought, but how could you apply that to the question?

Comment: He asked " can we find any operator that has no need for a semicolon?" 
So this may be helpful. But in updated question , description has been changed but may be helpful for someone else.